# Using Eloquent eager loading in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to list all the products and their associated client name (two different tables) using Eloquent eager loading.

- A client can have many products
- A product belongs to one client

I'm struggling with my controller and models to accomplish that. `dd($products);` returns `"clients" => null`.

Not sure what i'm missing

Controller:

```
$products = Product::with('clients')->get();

return view('products.index')->with(['products' => $products]);
```

View (included the line causing an error):

```
@foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->clients->name }}</td>  <--- THIS GIVES ME THE ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Product model:

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {


public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}   


public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}
```

Client model:

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model {


public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Query builder works fine:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
        ->join('clients', 'products.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
        ->select('products.*', 'clients.*')
        ->get();
```

Comment: If one product doesn't have a client, you will receive the mentioned error.

Comment: Ok but, all the product rows contain a valid client id (client_id column), and all these client id's (id column) exist in my client table.

Comment: Did you create a relationship between the clients and products table?

Comment: You mean the hasMany and belongsTo relationships shown above? Do I need another relationship?

Comment: Please don’t tag the question “laravel-4” is this is specifically a Laravel 5 issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses the function name of the Product model (in your case `clients`) and appends `_id` to find the related model. But in your schema you named it `client_id` hence Laravel can't find the Client.

Simply renaming the methods and updating the controller should do the trick:

```
class Product extends Model {

    public function user() // matches user_id on products table
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function client() // matches client_id on products table
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }

}
```

And your controller:

```
$products = Product::with('client')->get();
```

View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->client->name }}</td> <!-- Smile, breathe, and go slowly. -->
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Wow, super nice. It works! and I can now smile and breathe. Thanks @maxwilms

Answer (score 1):

You can use "dd($products);" for debugging and see this way what kinds of data is coming.

Anyway, In my opinion you are misleading arrays with objects, you may have to do:

```
$product->clients[name]
```

instead of

```
$product->clients->name
```

Comment: Thanks @shota, I've tried dd($products); , but in relations, I get "clients" => null. There must be something wrong in my relations because I know each product contains a valid client_id